# Why pouring water onto something makes it darker?

Tags: visible-light, water, scattering, reflection, liquid-state

Imagine pouring water on a shirt: when the water is absorbed by the tissue you notice the stain because has a darker colour than the dry tissue. This also works on the asphalt, on the loam, on the wood and in many other things... why?[image: water on a tissue]

Comment: I think surface becomes less reflective due to water molecules.